# Stored Procedure result is not showing in Datagrid pane in Toad for Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I have created a procedure in Toad for Oracle 12. When I execute the procedure it does not show the dataset in datagrid pane, while the procedure is being executed successfully. What I am doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FEEDERS_TO_MAKERS_MCB(OpNo CTS_OPERATIONS.OPERATIONNUM%Type ,BName CTS_OPERATIONS.BLENDNAME%Type) 
AS
p_recordset Types.cursor_type;
BEGIN
    OPEN p_recordset FOR

    SELECT FILLED_MCB.BARCODE,TILTED_MCB.TILTINGTIME,MAKERS.FEEDERNUM,MAKERS.MAKERNUM 
    FROM FILLED_MCB INNER JOIN TILTED_MCB ON FILLED_MCB.FM_ID = TILTED_MCB.FM_ID 
    INNER JOIN MAKERS ON MAKERS.M_ID = TILTED_MCB.M_ID 
    INNER JOIN CTS_OPERATIONS ON CTS_OPERATIONS.CTS_ID = FILLED_MCB.CTS_ID

    --WHERE CTS_OPERATIONS.OPERATIONNUM=OpNo AND CTS_OPERATIONS.BLENDNAME=BName;
    WHERE CTS_OPERATIONS.OPERATIONNUM=3004 AND CTS_OPERATIONS.BLENDNAME='PG';
END;
```

---- Execute Procedure ---------------

```
exec FEEDERS_TO_MAKERS_MCB(3004,'PG');
```

---

[image]

Comment: `p_recordset` is a local variable that goes out of scope as soon as the procedure returns.  If you want an object that executes a query and returns a `sys_refcursor` you probably want a function not a procedure.  If you really want to use a procedure, you'd need to add an `OUT` parameter of type `sys_refcursor` (or `types.cursor_type` if that is something meaningfully different).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an output parameter of the type `sys_refcursor`. Currently your cursor is assigned to a local variable, which gets destroyed when the procedure terminates.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FEEDERS_TO_MAKERS_MCB(
   OpNo CTS_OPERATIONS.OPERATIONNUM%Type 
   ,BName CTS_OPERATIONS.BLENDNAME%Type

   ,p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

) 
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_recordset FOR

    SELECT ...
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the cursor to ":data_grid" in order to show SP result in Toad Data Grid pane.

**SP exute script:**

[image]

**Press "F9" and bind it.** that is all

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should print your cursor content.

You can do it with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(...)

Or you could get ref cursor from your code and then print with "print" command (but you have to change procedure to function): great examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610495/how-to-see-refcursor-result-output-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score -1):

I always do it from the Schema Browser and let Toad handle it for me. Pick "Procedures" from the drop-down, right-click on your procedure, and select "Execute". A dialog will pop up, with a tab for output options. Select the option to load the cursor results into a data grid.

If you want to do it directly from the editor, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747823/how-to-display-a-sys-refcursor-data-in-toads-datagrid) and [this blog post](http://heather.koyuk.net/refractions/?p=343).

Answer (score -3):

If your script is correct and you are just not able to view the result in Data Grid then follow below steps, else ignore it.

Execute the script by

1. Pressing F9, Or
2. right click on then Execute --> Execute/Compile Statement,  Or
3. click on the button highlighted in the screenshot:
   [image]

Comment: The question was not "how to execute a script"...